# BitBucket Not Accepting my SSH Key?

Tags: git, github, ssh, mercurial, bitbucket

I am trying to push a new repository to bitbucket and I am getting blocked out due to the following error:

```
git init
git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:esend7881/node-chat-example.git
git add stuff
git commit -m 'Initial commi'
git push -u origin master
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

A little google research made me thing the command `ssh-keygen -t rsa` would help but it didn't help anything

Mind you, I do have a few repositories already that have worked fine. I think somewhere along the lines, my key got accidentally switched.

How I can start from scratch with these keys, regenerate new ones, register them on bitbucket itself and my local computers so I can go back to pushing like usual. (Note I use a few computers, so I was hoping just supplying my username and password to bitbucket would have sufficed. I wonder if an extra hard security setting got flagged accidentally?)

Answer (score 3):

Backup your ssh directory

```
mv ~/.ssh ~/.ssh.old
```

Generate a fresh pair of ssh keypair

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Use the default settings This step requires an optional passphrase. If you choose a passphrase, do remember it as there is no way of recovering it if it gets lost.

Now you should see id_rsa and id_rsa.pub files in your new ~/.ssh directory

```
ls -l ~/.ssh
id_rsa id_rsa.pub
```

The id_rsa is your private key. This should never be shared with **anyone**. The id_rsa.pub is your public key which is uploaded to sites like Github, Bitbucket, etc.

Goto Bitbucket -> Account -> SSH Keys

Delete all the old keys from there.

Click on Add Key. Give the key an appropriate name and paste the contents of `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` into the Key textbox

Copy this `~/.ssh` directory to all your computers. Make sure that the `.ssh` folder has 700 permission and all the files inside it have 400 permission on all your computers.

When you push for the first time, you might require to enter the ssh passphrase which you chose while generating the ssh keys.